# Excel Javascript API - setSelectedDataAsync with R1C1 formulas in Online Excel

Tags: office-js, excel-online

I have to use the setSelectedDataAsync method to insert data to a sheet coming from an API. There is quite a bit of data (1000 lines by 100 cols). In this data there are also formulas, coming in R1C1 format.
This works perfectly in my desktop Excel.

But in Excel online, they look like this:

[image: formulas not recognised]

I couldn't find a way to specify formulaR1C1.

the other option, getting the range and setting formulaR1C1 to the matrix, would work, but performance is terrible at that data volume.

Any alternatives? I am trying to publish my add-in to the store.

Answer (score 0):

it appears this feature isn't yet supported on Excel Online.To share your feedback, please upvote this user voice request: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-online/suggestions/8922370-r1c1-format

For your add-in, for now, it would mean refactoring it to use the A1 style of formula references to make it work for you users on Excel Online.